# NugGet Semver - what are allowed prerelease characters?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I'm trying to use semantic versioning for one of my NuGet Packages (.NET Core 2).

The version looks like this: `1.0.0-my_fancy_branch.123`.

As you can guess, I try to set the branch name and the current BuildId as a prerelease tag.

Unfortunately, dotnet build spews this error:

> ... is not a valid version string.

But why? The *absolutely great* documentation of dotnet push / nuget does not list any forbidden characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the reference on [NuGet package versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#semantic-versioning-200), NuGet uses [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) starting with NuGet 4.3.0. In earlier versions only a subset of SemVer 2.0.0 is supported, but this may still give a hint where the problem with the specified version is.

In [Section 9](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html#spec-item-9) (about pre-release versions) it is specified that

> Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII alphanumerics and hyphen `[0-9A-Za-z-]`.

Hence, I guess that the problems in your case are the underscores in the pre-release version.